# How do you get standard errors from GLM results in Python?

Tags: python, statsmodels, glm

I ran a regression something like,

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model import GLMResults

result = smf.glm(formula = 'y ~ x1 + x2', data = data).fit()
```

I could get estimates, p-values and number of observations by

`result.params, result.pvalues, result.nobs`

But how do you get standard errors?
I tried  `result.stand_errors` and it didn't work.

Also, please let me know what the other options I can use such as params, pvalues.. are.

Thank you.

Comment: Oh it seems like  result.bse works. Is this the way to get standard errors in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statsmodels documentation says that the attribute name is `bse`: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResults.html

So you can get `result.bse`.